# How to get select value of a HREF element through Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I have a HTML source.

```html
<div class="placeholderClass">
    <h2>THIS IS A PLACEHOLDER</h2> <br>
    <p>I want to redirect you to my website over here <a href="https://www.placeholder.com/path/app/stores/HubArticleView?hubId=Hub-100000&amp;placeHoldingID=100000&amp;userID=10000&amp;nameID=40&amp;viewID=10000#parentHorizontalTab2">PLACEHOLDER VIEW</a>.
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to get the href element from this source

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(body); // body is the HTML that is loaded above
const IDInfo = {};

const HREF = $('.placeholderClass > h2 > br > p[href])
```

I'm doing the last line to try and get the HREF link so I cant extract it.

Comment: You have syntax error missing closing quote in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fundamental thing about css selectors and jQuery/Cheerio. The attribute selector don't return attribute but node. What you want is this:

```js
$('.placeholderClass > h2 > br > p[href]').attr('href');
```

Answer (score -1):

**document.getElementByTagName("a").getAttribute("href");**

Comment: This probably will not work in Node since the OP don't use jsDom but Cheeerio. `document` object is (if not using jsDOM) the thing that live in the browser.